# copy npm global installed package to local

Tags: node.js, npm

If I have a npm package installed globally, and I want to install the same package locally in some project, does npm download the package again or copy it from the global install folder? If not, is there a way to make it do that?

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to copy files from global to local. It is pretty normal to have package installed in both places.

- Global package in most of the cases is used in terminal.
- Local package is used in application itself.

Also you can use **npm link** to symlink a global package

> 1. Install it in both places. Seriously, are you that short on disk
>    space? It’s fine, really. They’re tiny JavaScript programs.
> 2. Install it
>    globally, and then **npm link coffee-script** or **npm link express** (if
>    you’re on a platform that supports symbolic links.) Then you only need
>    to update the global copy to update all the symlinks as well.
>
> The first option is the best in my opinion. Simple, clear, explicit. The
> second is really handy if you are going to re-use the same library in
> a bunch of different projects. (More on **npm link** in a future
> installment.)

Comment: He said `copy`. I think he could be trying to avoid another download, like me right now in a poor internet connection...