# How to install all existing global NPM packages into local directory?

Tags: node.js, npm

This is not similar nor does it answer question: [copy npm global installed package to local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277639/copy-npm-global-installed-package-to-local)

Basically I want to tell NPM, look at what I have installed globally, and install that locally.

I'm not interested in the symlinks, but if above is not possible, could I use a single symlink to node_modules instead of a symlink for each package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the output of `node ls -g --depth 0` and `npm install` the resulting list of packages.

```
npm i -S -dd $(npm ls -g --depth 0 | tail -n +2 | cut -c 5- | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Run this command in the directory of the package that you wish to install global packages to.

Explanation:

`npm i -S -dd` Shorthand for `npm install --save --verbose`. The `-S` is unnecessary on recent npm versions that save installed packages to package.json by default.

`npm ls -g --depth 0` List first-level global packages.

`tail -n +2` Remove the first line from the output.

`cut -c 5-` Remove the first four characters from each line in the output.

`tr '\n' ' '` Combine each line to place all packages on one line, separated by spaces.

Comment: All good, just as an fyi, after that command, tracker-miner-f pegged cpu.